# modbus Hex address Conversion

Tags: c, modbus, modbus-tcp

I am trying to read data from GE-PQM II energy meter. Energy meter supports real time monitoring via 2 wire RS-485 MODBUS connection. I use libmodbus library in c to read modbus registers.

In GE communication guide (https://www.ccontrols.com/support/dp/GEK-113532.pdf) the address of the register are given in hexadecimal. I converted hex to decimal.

I am trying to read values from modbus register (02F0,02F1) - corresponding decimal values are 752,753

[GE-PQM sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtwC4.png)

My code:

```
rc = modbus_read_registers(ctx, 752, 753, clock);
```

output :

```
ERROR Too many registers requested (753 > 125)
Too many data
```

Anything wrong in hex conversion ?  or some where else?

Comment: Did you actually read the [documentation for modbus_read_registers](http://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/3/modbus_read_registers/)? When there is an error, the first thing to do should be to consult the documentation. Check what the third parameter is supposed to be.

Comment: If you use this [libmodbus](http://libmodbus.org/), so in function call `int modbus_read_registers(modbus_t *ctx, int addr, **int nb**, uint16_t *dest);` parameter `nb` is number of register for read and it must be equal 2 and not 753.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !!

Comment: It my fault that i missed it.

Comment: No need to convert to decimal either, just use 0x2F0 for address.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this [libmodbus](http://libmodbus.org/), so in function call

```
int modbus_read_registers(modbus_t *ctx, int addr, int nb, uint16_t *dest);
```

parameter `nb` is number of register for read and it must be equal 2 and not 753. – imbearr